# Why do my texture does not show up?

Tags: texturing

[image]

I don't know why my texture just doesnt apply and show up on certain faces. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you in Solid mode? In Solid mode, by default, you won't see the material. Please tell a bit more

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a color to show up in solid shading, you'll have to add it in the *viewport display* section of your material properties. You must have done the same at some point for the arcade controls to appear red, green and blue.